# Better understanding of Rails sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails sessions with the default Cookie Store, and I'm accessing the session object and reading/writing variables with

```
session[:my_var] = 'abc'
```

I can load an action on my app which sets this session variable, and look at my "_appname_session" cookie in my browser.  Viewing the contents of this cookie in the rails console, via

```
Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(CGI.unescape("[paste cookie here]".split("\n").join).split('--').first))
```

I see

```
{:session_id=>"[some long key]", :my_var=> 'abc'}
```

All good.

If I load another action, which contains the code

```
session[:another_var] = 'abc'
```

I decode the cookie again, but this time see

```
{:session_id=>"[a different key]", :another_var=> 'abc'}
```

So my question is, why am I seeing a different value for :session_id, and where has my :my_var in the session object/cookie gone to?

Also-- I have tried this example using Active Record Store, and see the same results, now in my database, showing up as a new row in the sessions table.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Same browser? Same browser window? Which browser?

Comment: Are you sure the session isn't being cleared somewhere, like tucked away in an ApplicationController before_filter?

Comment: I think you need to show more code. This is non-standard behavior, so something else must be interfering.

Comment: @BenLee you know what, I knew it had to be something ridiculously simple that I was missing.  In fact, there was some code in my authenticated_system that was resetting the session for logged out users.  Thanks for helping track this down, and sorry for the misguided question!

Answer (score -2):

`session[:my_var]`and `session[:another_var]` is **not one session** with two variables but two different sessions altogether.

I think what you want to do is making one session and assign your variables through a hash to it:

```
session[:my_session] = {:my_var => "abc", :another_var => "abc"}
```

See [the "What are Sessions?" section in the Rails guides for more details](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions).

Comment: I think the point is that it's unclear *why* there are two sessions. `session[:my_var]` and `session[:another_var]` *should* be the same session if it's the same browser/same tab/same user (if there are logins). `session` is *the* session for a single conversation.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.  Why is "session" behaving as two different objects across requests?